# How to split data frame into x and y

Tags: python, numpy

I am splitting the data into training data and testing data like so:

```
train, test = train_test_split(dataFrame(), test_size=0.2)
```

Which works wonders, my training data frame looks like this:

```
     PassengerId  Survived  SibSp  Parch
77            78         0      0      0
748          749         0      1      0
444          445         1      0      0
361          362         0      1      0
576          577         1      0      0
27            28         0      3      2
232          233         0      0      0
424          425         0      1      1
785          786         0      0      0
…            …           …      …      …
```

I am now attempting to get the X and Y columns, X being my SibSp column and Y being my Parch column. After following many [tutorials on Regression](https://utkuufuk.github.io/2018/05/19/binary-logistic-regression/) and training my AI, every person "split" the columns into x and y like so:

```
x = train[:, 0:2]
```

However, after many variations and googling, I cannot solve this error this line is giving me nor understand it:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

How can I split the SibSp column into an array of x and the Parch column into an array of y within my training data frame?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The correct way to slice is `x = train.iloc[:, 0:2]`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! In my case, Its now `train.iloc[:, 2:3]` for x! Thanks so much - I'll mark when I can.

Comment: @Danny_P Just know syntax is `iloc[rows, cols]` and reference [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position).

Answer (score 3):

If your target class is the **last** column, the most generic solution is:

```
X = df.iloc[:, 0:-1]
y = df.iloc[:, -1]
```