# How to plot a line on a scatter graph based on theta from regression in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, logistic-regression

I am calculating the theta for my AI like so:

```
theta = opt.fmin_cg(cost, initial_theta, gradient, (newX, y))
```

Which works great and gives me this output:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.684355
         Iterations: 6
         Function evaluations: 15
         Gradient evaluations: 15
```

When I print theta, I get this:

```
[ 0.         -0.28132729  0.158859  ]
```

I now want to plot this on my scatter graph as a line, my expected output looks like this:

[image: Expected Output]

But when I try to perform this on my graph with the algorithm:

```
weights * features = weight0 + weight1 * feature1 + weight2 * feature2
```

Like so:

```
x_axis = np.array([min(newX[:, 1]), max(newX[:, 1])])
y_axis = x_axis * theta[1:]
ax.plot(x_axis, y_axis, linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Actual Output]

**What should `y_axis = x_axis * theta[1:]` be to match the algorithm?**

> Update:

`newX` derives from my training data frame and is created like this:

```
newX = np.zeros(shape=(x.shape[0], x.shape[1] + 1))
newX[:, 1:] = x.values
```

It now looks like this, the concept is 0 is the free weight:

```
[[0. 8. 2.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1.]]
```

Comment: Before you figure out `y_axis`, what is or how are you getting `newX`? `x_axis` doesn't seem to match what you want.

Comment: Updated the question for you @busybear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you are trying to plot your decision boundary for the logistic regression. This is not simply a y = mx + b problem, well it is but you first need to determine where your decision boundary is, typically it's at probability of 0.5. I assume the model you are going with something looks like `h(x) = g(theta_0*x_0 + theta_1*x_1 + theta_2*x_2)`, where `g(x) = 1 / (1 + e^-x)` and `x_1` and `x_2` are your features that you are plotting, ie your y and x axis (I don't know which is y and which is x since I don't know your data). So for probability 0.5, you want to solve for `h(x) = 0.5`, ie `theta_0*x_0 + theta_1*x_1 + theta_2*x_2 = 0`

So what you want to plot is the line `0 = theta_0*x_0 + theta_1*x_1 + theta_2*x_2`. Let's just say you have `x_1` on your x axis and `x_2` on your y axis. (`x_0` is just `1`, corresponding to `theta_0`, your intercept.)

So you'll need to pick (somewhat arbitrarily) `x_1` values that will give you a good illustration of the boundary line. Min/max of your dataset works, which you've done. Then solve for `x_2` given the formula above. You can define a function here: `lambda x_1: (theta[0] + theta[1] * x_1) / theta[2]`. I'm assuming your `theta` variable corresponds to `[intercept, coeff for x_1, coeff for x_2]`. So you'll end up with something like:

```
theta = [0., -0.28132729, 0.158859]
x = np.array([0, 10])
f = lambda x_1: (theta[0] + theta[1] * x_1) / theta[2]
y = f(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarity, this has helped a lot!

Comment: I think `x` contains two features, `newX` has added a new column with `0` values to act as a free weight and he is trying to show the line based on the prediction. So his line should go from 3.5 (x_axis) to 3.5 (y_axis) based on his data. since the regression should see that from 3.5 (ish) the survival rate drops to 0 on average. I got the data from his previous [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991131/how-to-split-data-frame-into-x-and-y) and [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029900/how-to-fill-an-nparray-with-another-array-starting-at-a-key-in-python)